# MongoDB query to handle/fetch inner array (Need to apply pagination in inner array)

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents like below,

```
Document1:

{
    name: "tester1",
    reports: [{
            name: "report1",
            type: "overflow"
        },
        {
            name: "report2",
            type: "invalid form"
        }
    ]
}

Document2:

{
    name: "tester2",
    reports: [{
            name: "report3",
            type: "crossed"
        },
        {
            name: "report4",
            type: "unknown issue"
        }
    ]
} 

Document3:
{
    name: "tester3",
    reports: [{
            name: "report4",
            type: "try again"
        },
        {
            name: "report6",
            type: "invalid data"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to implement query to fetch data like,

```
[{
        name: "report1",
        type: "overflow"
    },
    {
        name: "report2",
        type: "invalid form"
    },
    {
        name: "report3",
        type: "crossed"
    },
    {
        name: "report4",
        type: "unknown issue"
    },
    {
        name: "report4",
        type: "try again"
    },
    {
        name: "report6",
        type: "invalid data"
    }
]
```

I tried using grouping and projecting but unable to generate this output.

I need only inner arrays as final documents so that I can apply aggregation queries to achieve pagination and search.

Comment: Each document contains above array? I am trying to understand your document

Comment: No, I have added three documents with data

Comment: What kind of "search" you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) along with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) in order to promote `reports` to the root level and then you can use [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/index.html) or [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$reports" },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$reports" } },
    { $limit: 5 }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kDg1jda8a8f)